# Compass Sprite Sheet Paths with Webroot Folder

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I have been fighting with pathing for Compass Sprites for a couple days now.

I have the following structure to my site:

```
+ project
    - config.rb
    + application
        + scss
            - _base.scss
            - main.scss
            - ...
    + public (webroot)
        + js
        + css
            - main.css
        + images
            + sprites
                - boxarrow.png
                - boxcheck.png
                - ...
```

My config.rb initially looked something like:

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "public/css"
sass_dir = "application/scss"
images_dir = "public/images"
javascripts_dir = "public/js"
```

Within my scss file I am using the following to scan my sprites:

```
$sprites: sprite-map("sprites/*.png");
```

And use them with a mixin I wrote:

```
@mixin scaled-sprite-background($name, $scale, $spritemap) {
    background: $spritemap;

    $spritePath: sprite-path($spritemap);
    @include background-size(image-width($spritePath) * $scale);

    $position: sprite-position($spritemap, $name);
    background-position: (nth($position, 1) * $scale) (nth($position, 2) * $scale);

    height: image-height(sprite-file($spritemap, $name)) * $scale;
    width: image-width(sprite-file($spritemap, $name)) * $scale;
}
```

The problem was my sprite paths were coming out ala `public/images/sprites-s500a0fe4b1.png` whereas they should not have the public/.

I removed the `public/` so I had just `images_dir = "images"` but now compass couldn't locate my images.

I set `http_path = "public"` and got *double public* `public/public/images/sprites-s500a0fe4b1.png`

I tried many more configurations using images_path and such to no avail.

The working hack I have currently follows:

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "public/css"
sass_dir = "application/scss"
images_dir = "images"
images_path = "public/images"
javascripts_dir = "public/js"

on_sprite_saved do |filename|
  FileUtils.mv(filename, images_path + "/" + File.basename( filename )) if File.exists?(filename)
end
```

Its not pretty but it works.  Surely there needs to be a better way!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `images_dir = "/images"` or `images_dir = "../images"` ?

Comment: @morkro Yep, both give me "No files were found in the load path matching "sprites/*.png". Your current load paths are: /Users/jdonat/Sites/capsis/images"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Relative assets

If you want to use relative path between images and CSS (ie `background: url('../images/foo.png')`), you have to add `relative_assets = true` in your configuration file:

```
css_dir = "public/css"
sass_dir = "application/scss"
images_dir = "public/images"
javascripts_dir = "public/js"
relative_assets = true
```

With this, Compass will ignore the `http_path` option and will generate the access to the images relative to the location of the CSS file paths.

#### Absolute assets

If you want to use absolute paths to access to your images (ie `background: url('/images/foo.png')`, according the [configuration reference](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/), remember that the local paths `*_path` are different of the full http path `http_*_path`.

So, to access to the images stored in `public/images` when the webroot is `public`, you have to work in two times:

1. you have to tell to Compass that the images are stored locally in the `public/images` directory: `images_dir = "public/images"`.
2. the full http path must be configured: `http_images_path = "/images"` for regular images (when you use the helper `image-url()`) and `http_generated_images_path = "/images"` for generated sprites.

The final configuration file becomes:

```
css_dir = "public/css"
sass_dir = "application/scss"
images_dir = "public/images"
javascripts_dir = "public/js"
http_images_path = "/images"
http_generated_images_path = "/images"
```

Comment: This answered my question! Thank you!